# Delphi SQL - CommandText does not return a result set

Tags: delphi

I want to delete rows from a grid when I click on a button. How can I do that?

```pascal
procedure TFormAna.ptal1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  QSilMaster.Close;
  QSilDetay.Close;
  QSilMaster.SQL.Text:='delete from IsTakipMaster where id=:pMasterid';
  QSilDetay.SQL.Text:='delete from IsTakipDetay where Masterid=:pid';
  QSilMaster.ExecSQL;
  QSilDetay.ExecSQL;
  QSilMaster.Open;
  QSilDetay.Open;
  //dm.QGenel.Parameters.ParamValues['pid']:=QSilMasterid.Value;
  //dm.QGenel.Parameters.ParamValues['pMasterid']:=QSilDetayMasterid.Value;
  QSilMasterid.Value:=QSilDetayMasterid.Value;
end;
```

I get this error message:

> CommandText does not return a result set

Why do I get this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `DELETE` does not return a result set, because it does a `DELETE`. What result set would you expect? The DELETEd rows? They can't be returned - they've been deleted. `DELETE`, `INSERT` and `UPDATE` will tell you how many rows were changed with the `RowsAffected` property. `SELECT` returns a result set. You're getting the error on the calls to `Open`, which are only used for `SELECT`. Use `ExecSQL` for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the component you use for QSilMaster and QSilDetay. But usually you call either `ExecSQL` or `Open` but not both. Use `ExecSQL` for a request which doesn't return any result set (such as your DELETE) and `Open` for a request returning a result set (Such as a SELECT).

Comment: @berk Cinaz Sorry to bother you more, but you still have not accepted my answer. It is the "tick mark" that you have to use.